# How do I force two Box2D bodies to avoid colliding when they spawn on top of each other?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm in the process of creating a sidescrolling action game where you play a wizard that can cast spells. The spells are Box2D bodies that start in the middle of your player (who is also a Box2D body) and go outward in the direction you clicked on the screen.

I have all the collision detection working to where the spells you cast don't collide with each other and they don't collide with you. This works more-or-less flawlessly -- except for one instance. The first spell I cast creates a collision with the player that causes a brief period of physical knockback. The spell's path is not affected otherwise, and I don't notice a major change in the player's position. The only reason I know there is knockback at all is because the camera I have following the player suddenly shakes in that instant (and I've gone through the contact listener to verify that these particular bodies are forming a contact).

This is not the case for subsequent spells that are spawned from the same position, and it doesn't seem to be a problem that is related to the player's move speed or the projectile's cast angle. It may have something to do with how Box2D initializes items, but I couldn't promise that.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: You need to show the relevant code or ideally a new minimal example that exhibits the behaviour http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/360211.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out where the problem was and how to solve it, but I wasn't able to fight out why it was happening.

I was using an OrthographicCamera to lerp to my player's position.

```
position.x += (universe.entity_handler.player.parts[0].body.getPosition().x - position.x) * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 
position.y += (universe.entity_handler.player.parts[0].body.getPosition().y - position.y) * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * LERP + zoom * viewportHeight / WORLD_PLAYER_Y_SKEW;
```

And when I fixed this by removing all lerping, the jitter was gone.

```
position.x = universe.entity_handler.player.parts[0].body.getPosition().x;
position.y = universe.entity_handler.player.parts[0].body.getPosition().y;
```

I have zero idea why linear interpolation was causing spastic movements like that, but hey - I got it to work. Maybe I'll go back and revisit the problem later.

Answer (score 0):

As weston mentioned, some more code may be needed, but it does sound odd that "the first spell" does this, but subsequent spawnings don't. Do you reuse bodies for subsequent spawns?

In box2d if you create 2 bodies that occupy the same space they will "knockback" from each other so that they DON'T occupy the same space. This is by design, and only happens on creation. I'm sure this is what you're seeing. Why it doesn't happen "afterwards" may be dependent on your code.

Ways around this might be to set some of your fixtures as sensors for a bit (collisions are ignored), or when you create a body, set active=false (again, collisions ignored). By "for a bit" I mean you may have to write some code to move your spell, ignoring collisions, until your spell has "cleared" your wizard. Then remove the sensor or make it active so collisions are back in play.

But that may be overkill, figuring out the subtlety of subsequent "spans" vs. your first one may be a better use of effort.